# Using certain functions from stdlib.h or stdio.h causes syntax errors

Tags: c, syntax-error

I'm working on some C code in Visual Studio 2005 on Win7 Pro x64.  The code is correct; it compiles and runs on MinGW under Eclipse.  However, using certain functions from the standard C libraries like stdio or stdlib causes the following lines to exhibit syntax errors when the code is built in VS2005.  As an example:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"someOtherHeader.h"

int main(void){
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    double start;
.
.
.
```

The following code doesn't matter.  VS2005 says that there is a missing ';' before 'type'.  Commenting out srand() fixes the problem.  Oddly, when rand() is called later, there is no problem.  I also noticed the behavior with exit() and fprint().  But not with malloc().  Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using C in Visual Studio puts the compiler into strict (old school C) mode. All your declarations have to be at the beginning of your blocks:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"someOtherHeader.h"

int main(void){
    double start;
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio supports NOT C99 (just a little bit)