# peculiar visual studio compile error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know why this code variation compiles and runs under Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *myfunc(char *c, int i) {
    c[0] = (char)i;
    c[1] = 0;
    return c;
}

int main(void) {

    char str[5]; //////////////////////////////

    char *(*fun)(char *, int);
    fun = myfunc;



    puts(fun(str, 51));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But this one doesn't

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *myfunc(char *c, int i) {
    c[0] = (char)i;
    c[1] = 0;
    return c;
}

int main(void) {



    char *(*fun)(char *, int);
    fun = myfunc;

    char str[5]; //////////////////////////////

    puts(fun(str, 51));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The second variation returns these errors

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2065: 'str' : undeclared identifier

It works just fine either way with mingw gcc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218066/does-anyone-know-the-reason-why-the-variables-have-to-be-defined-at-the-top-of-f

Comment: Or upgrade to a standard compliant C compiler...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409299/using-certain-functions-from-stdlib-h-or-stdio-h-causes-syntax-errors/3410161#3410161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 supports the old version of C,i.e, C89 or ANSI C.

In C89, variables have to be declared at the start of a block. Unlike newer versions of C, it does not support mixed declarations. So, you are forced to declare variables just after `{`.

GCC supports mixed declarations as [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Mixed-Declarations.html#Mixed-Declarations) which explains why the code compiles without any problems in GCC.

Comment: It works in gcc because it is a conforming C compiler, simple as that. It has nothing to do with GNU extensions. Unlike Visual Studio, gcc is up to date with everything that has happened to the C language during the past 25 years.

Comment: Thank you. Is there somewhere I can look to see which versions of Visual Studio support which standard?

Comment: @Lundin , By default, GCC, without an `-std` flag, compiles in C89, right? So , isn't it because of the extension?

Comment: By default, GCC compiles in non-standard mode. It is some version which comes as "C11 and then some". It is much more lax when compiling than when you add `-std` and `-pedantic-errors` flags (which is why those flags are great). If you compile as for example `-std=c90 -pedantic-errors`, the K&R code won't compile.